# How to select marker entry from Markers view

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am trying to convert a marker entry to a customized object , and aiming to perform the same by right clicking on the Marker entry in the Marker Table View, and calling an action/handler from an option in the context menu.

But in the handler when i try to access the selection, the object being returned is an `MarkerEntry` (*org.eclipse.ui.internal.views.markers.MarkerEntry*), rather than an `IMarker`. Since MarkerEntry is an internal class, not sure how to use it and also if its safe to use it.

Please suggest any solution/alternative. Relevant Code and *plugin.xml* snippet below

**plugin.xml**

```
<extension point="org.eclipse.ui.views"> 
    <view class="view.ReviewMarkerView" icon="icons/insta_window_16.png" id="id.instaReviewMarkerView" name="Insta Review Defects"> </view>
</extension>

<extension point="org.eclipse.ui.commands">
    <command defaultHandler="handlers.DefectToReviewIssueHandler" id="id.defectToReviewIssueHandler" name="Add defect to Review Tracker"></command>
</extension>

<extension point="org.eclipse.ui.menus">    
    <menuContribution locationURI="popup:id.instaReviewMarkerView">
        <command commandId="id.defectToReviewIssueHandler" style="push"></command>
    </menuContribution>
</extension>
```

**Java class:**

```
public class MarkerToReviewIssueHandler extends AbstractHandler {

    public MarkerToReviewIssueHandler() {
    }

    public Object execute(ExecutionEvent event) throws ExecutionException {

        IWorkbenchWindow window = HandlerUtil.getActiveWorkbenchWindowChecked(event);

        IWorkbenchPage page = window.getActivePage();

        ReviewMarkerView view = (ReviewMarkerView) page.findView("id.instaReviewMarkerView");

        ISelection sel = view.getSite().getSelectionProvider().getSelection();

        if (sel != null && sel instanceof IStructuredSelection) {

            Iterator iterator = (IStructuredSelection) sel).iterator();

            while (iterator.hasNext()) {

                Object item = iterator.next();

                if (item instanceof IMarker) {

                    // convert the marker to a review issue.
                }
            }

        } else {
            //Show error to select a review defect
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you say `MarkerEntry` is internal so you should not reference the class directly.

However `MarkerEntry` does implement `IAdaptable` and this provides a way to get the `IMarker`:

```
if (item instanceof IAdaptable)
 {
   IAdaptable adaptable = (IAdaptable)item;

   IMarker marker = (IMarker)adaptable.getAdapter(IMarker.class);
 }
```

Comment: Fantastic !! Very elegant solution indeed.